# getCensus Hawaii City Populations

Tags: r

I'm looking to gather populations for Hawaiian cities and am puzzled how to collect it using the `censusapi` getCensus() function.

```
census_api_key(key='YOURKEYHERE')

newpopvars <- listCensusMetadata(name = "2017/pep/population", type = "variables")

usapops <- getCensus(name = "pep/population",
                vintage = 2017,
                vars = c(newpopvars$name),
                region = "place:*")

usapops <- usapops[which(usapops$DATE_==10),]

state <- grepl("Hawaii", usapops$GEONAME)
cities <- data.frame()
for (i in seq(1,length(state))) {
  if (state[i] == TRUE) {
    cities <- rbind(cities,usapops[i,]) 
  }
}
```

This returns only two cities but certainly there are more than that in Hawaii. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did some further investigations and it looks like there is only ONE Hawaii entry for cities / towns in the USA census, at least up until 2018. https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk Why, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one place (Census summary level 160) in Hawaii which is large enough to be included in the 1-year American Community Survey release: "Urban Honolulu" (GeoID 1571550).  The 1-year release only includes places with 65,000+ population.  I assume similar controls apply to the Population Estimates program -- I couldn't find it stated directly, but the section header on [the page for  Population Estimates downloads for cities and towns](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/time-series/demo/popest/2010s-total-cities-and-towns.html#tables) says "Places of 50,000 or More" -- the second most populated CDP in Hawaii is East Honolulu, which had only 47,868 in the 2013-2017 ACS release.

If you use the ACS 5-year data release, you'll find 151 places at summary level 160.

It looks as though you should change `pep/population` to `acs/acs5` in your `getCensus` call. I don't know the specific variables for the API, but if you just want total population for places, use the ACS B01003 table, which has a single column with that value.

Comment: Thank you for drawing my attention to the "Places of 50,000 or more" header and `acs/acs5`!

Comment: On further inspection, I am not sure if the "50,000 or more" criteria is applied consistently. For example, see https://factfinder.census.gov/faces/tableservices/jsf/pages/productview.xhtml?src=bkmk

Comment: @Justapigeon FYI you generally can't just copy/paste links into American Fact Finder -- you need to click "bookmark/save" on a data page to get a shareable URL.  So I'm not sure to what you're pointing above!

Comment: Oops: https://factfinder.census.gov/bkmk/table/1.0/en/PEP/2018/PEPANNRES/0400000US31.16200

Comment: Interesting. I noticed in the URL you shared that it ends in `.16200` -- that means, Summary Level 162.  I am not able to find that summary level in official Census documentation, but this page from the MCDC explains that 162 means "does not include CDPs" http://mcdc.missouri.edu/geography/sumlevs/  It turns out that Honolulu is the only municipality in Hawaii; all other "places" are CDPs (Census Designated Places)... not sure why CDPs are excluded; MCDC's doc is about the 2000 Decennial census, but it fits this scenario.

Comment: Your expertise on this matter has been much appreciated. With all these "codes" and excess of information, it has been really difficult to decipher what I need to extract populations for my project--so suffice to say that this info is greatly valued!